# how to link lpng package

Tags: visual-c++, boost, linker-errors, libpng, boost-gil

I use VC++, boost::gil package and lpng package to read a png image. After debuging I have
following linking problem:

```
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_set_swap img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_get_bit_depth    img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_read_info    img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_set_sig_bytes    img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_init_io  img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_set_longjmp_fn   img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_destroy_read_struct  img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_create_info_struct   img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_create_read_struct   img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_sig_cmp  img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_get_image_width  img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_get_image_height img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_read_end img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_read_row img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _png_get_IHDR img_seq_interp.obj  img_seq_interp
Error   18  fatal error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals    C:\Studium\codes\vc++\img_seq_interp\Debug\img_seq_interp.exe   img_seq_interp
```

How does it come from? Do I need some lib to link the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need some lib to link the problem?

Yes, you have to link `libpng`.

Comment: Thank you! But to link the whole Folder or certain lib of libpng?